# can't do anything on sda1 permission denied

Tags: hard-drive

Main system is on sdb (ssd). Got an HDD on sda1 (that's the partition I want to use), but getting permission denied when doing anything on it. Want it to be mounted and ready for use each time I boot the computer like it's regular space for downloading stuff.

Lubuntu 18.04.2

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   436G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0  74.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0    74G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Providing more details may help us to help you.  How are you trying to mount it when you get the permission-denied error?  If you're doing it from a command line, please provide command & error-message-output.  Did you use `sudo` to elevate permissions?  If done via gui, what tool did you use to perform mount, what type of file system is on the drive? We only know what you tell us...

Comment: I just click on the partition in PCManFM. When I create a new folder, I get an error. I want read/write functionality in this fashion to work on boot.

Comment: Where are you trying to create the new folder, if it's in $HOME (ie. your /home/user/ directory) you have permissions, however if it's elsewhere in the file-system you need to elevate permissions (eg. `sudo mkdir /my_new_mount_dir` if using command).  Details provided by you help us to understand your issue & help you more directly. If you want it to mount directly, I'd suggest adding an entry in `/etc/fstab` (your system's file-system table) but more details are necessary for full details needed (eg. `lsblk` will list devices, I'd suggest using UUID= detail in entry)

Comment: So I can never do anything outside home w/o root? But I modify files on a USB flash drive all the time w/o root. Or are you saying fstab will fix this?

Comment: You need to have a directory first in order to mount to it, that will require `sudo` or elevated-privileges unless it's auto-mounted like you're probably doing already with the thumb-drives.  Its needed only to create the directory, then edit the fstab file & setup your configuration; it won't be necessary to use it (as you can give your $USER read/write permissions to the directory after creation).

Comment: `NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   436G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0  74.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0    74G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, we can help you format it correctly in questions & answers.

Comment: OK, done. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a mount point you want to use

> sudo mkdir /data

Where you create the directory is up to you, I have a few in my / (root) directory to save typing when I refer to them.  'data' is used as an example.

2. get details of your drive/partitions

> ```
> guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   sudo blkid |grep UUID
> /dev/sda1: UUID="afa7971f-3dd5-4b30-9c98-0af3e56a6f2b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-01"
> /dev/sda2: UUID="4f59600e-1f6b-4e3a-a466-941a2168e327" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-02"
> /dev/sda4: UUID="06863296-81b3-4263-8665-21f1864fa399" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-04"
> /dev/sda5: UUID="5b4267e5-8b90-4f6b-84b0-c4ee9d5e104d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-05"
> /dev/sda6: UUID="ba0dca2e-0799-4340-b565-a649842c8a69" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-06"
> guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   cat /etc/fstab|grep UUID
> UUID=afa7971f-3dd5-4b30-9c98-0af3e56a6f2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> UUID=06863296-81b3-4263-8665-21f1864fa399 /home           xfs     defaults        0       0
> UUID=4f59600e-1f6b-4e3a-a466-941a2168e327       none            swap    sw      0 0
> ```

You'll note the detail for /sda6 (which I don't refer to by /dev/sda6 as those numbers can change if bios configuration is altered. partitioning changes, etc - I use the more precise UUID or unique-identifier for the partition.

The 'xfs' parameter you will need to change to reflect the type of file-system you are use for that partition, i use 'xfs' obviously, but you could say 'ext4' if that's what you use, or your type of fs.  From `man fstab` some examples are :-

> ```
>    The third field (fs_vfstype).
>           This  field  describes  the  type of the filesystem.  Linux supports many filesystem types: ext4, xfs, btrfs, f2fs, vfat,
>           ntfs, hfsplus, tmpfs, sysfs, proc, iso9660, udf, squashfs, nfs, cifs, and many more.  For more details, see mount(8).
> ```

3. Add new entry to your file-system table  (/etc/fstab)

You adjust what you learned in prior steps to your drive/partition entries.  Your best examples of course will not be mine, but your own existing entries in `/etc/fstab` or your own file-system table.  This will create a line you add below the already existing entries in your 'fstab' file.  I'd also suggest adding a comment to it as to who made change, why, for example

```
\# adding my /dev/sda6 so it'll automount - guiverc/2019-03
UUID=ba0dca2e-0799-4340-b565-a649842c8a69       /data           xfs             defaults        0 0
```

What editor you use to edit `/etc/fstab` to add the additional entry is up to you, but you'll need to elevate your privileges, for example `sudo vim /etc/fstab`.  It can also be done by GUI, but I find commands far faster.

You can then test with `sudo mount /data`, and it should automount in subsequent boots.

Comment: Thanks, though I must add another necessary step, since this procedure merely mounted the drive to /data. It did NOT make it so that I can do anything in it without elevated procedures. I had to run pcmanfm in sudo and change /data permissions to be capable of edited by Anyone. After that it seems to have started working.

Comment: Is your filesystem a native of linux (eg. ext4 etc), or a foreign one (ntfs etc)?   I didn't do it, but yes I may have `sudo chown $USER /data/`if necessary in testing. (but I recall it only being necessary for non-native file-systems..)

Comment: It's ext4 created with GParted on this OS

Comment: If you're happy with answer; please accept. If you want me to add an additional step (`sudo chown $USER /data`) I can; I'm reluctant to only because I didn't require it on test (though I mounted `nfs` type)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to unmount it (Remember to use sudo)-

`sudo umount /dev/sda1`

Then you need to properly mount it but before that double-check

`lsblk`

Make sure this is the partition you want to mount

Create a directory in `/mnt/` with your favorite name say 'sda1'

`sudo mkdir /mnt/sda1`

Now mount the partition to the directory

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1`

Comment: sudo mount /dev/sda1/ /mnt/sda1
mount: /mnt/sda1: special device /dev/sda1/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).

Comment: There's an extra / after `/dev/sda1`